# Pandas SparseDtype not working with GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
data.groupby(by="DAY").agg({"CLOSING_DATE": min})
```

How come that when I tried to groupby my dataframe to get the oldest date for a sparse column (CLOSING_DATE is mostly empty) I get the following error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-23-37f9fe161304>", line 1, in <module>
data[:10000].groupby(by="DAY").agg({"CLOSING_DATE": min})
File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/churn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 951, in aggregate
result, how = self._aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 416, in _aggregate
result = _agg(arg, _agg_1dim)
File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 383, in _agg
result[fname] = func(fname, agg_how)
File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 367, in _agg_1dim
return colg.aggregate(how)
File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 252, in aggregate
return getattr(self, cyfunc)()
File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 1553, in min
return self._agg_general(
File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 1000, in _agg_general
result = self._cython_agg_general(
File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 1035, in _cython_agg_general
result, agg_names = self.grouper.aggregate(
File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 591, in aggregate
return self._cython_operation(
File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/py_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 471, in _cython_operation
raise NotImplementedError(f"{values.dtype} dtype not supported")
NotImplementedError: Sparse[float64, nan] dtype not supported
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in pandas, related to a recent refactor of cython optimized groupbys:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/38980

You have two choices:

1. Downgrade the version of pandas you're using to 1.1.4 and wait for the bug to be fixed (maybe ~4-6 weeks)
2. Convert your sparse matrix to a dense matrix before the groupby with `to_dense()`

Comment: Thanks - `to_dense()` seems the quickest work-around

Comment: Happy to help. FYI, if you accept the answer, it will help others find it faster.

Comment: At the end I did actually just convert to `category` the dtype instead of using `to_dense()`